# request to custom host rather than domain name in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Even after setting the host in the adapter in ember-cli the request is sent to the page domain:

adapters/students.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
     host:"localhost:8080/Hello"
});
```

routes/students.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function(){
          return this.store.find('students');
     }
});
```

When the students template is loaded it sends the request to "localhost:4200/students" and gives an error `GET localhost:4200/students 404 (Not Found)`.  The app is served on localhost:4200, but the request should be sent to "localhost:8080/Hello/students".

Answer (score 2):

Your adapter file should be named `adapters/application.js`.  You will also need to update the adapter file to something like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8080',
    namespace: 'Hello'
})
```

Also, make sure you are starting your application like this:

`ember server --proxy http://localhost:8080`